# In Meteor how can I tell if my template is being used as a block helper?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to write a template which will sometimes be used as a block helper, something like this:

```
<template name="helpText">
  {{#if isBlockHelper}}
    {{> UI.contentBlock}} 
  {{else}}
    Looks like there's nothing to display!
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Is there any way to do this in meteor?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's pretty simple:

```
<template name="helpText">
  {{#if UI.contentBlock}}
    {{> UI.contentBlock}} 
  {{else}}
    Looks like there's nothing to display!
  {{/if}}
</template>
```